# Alternative to New-SqlAzureKeyVaultColumnMasterKeySettings

Tags: azure, powershell

I currently have a script that is similair to the script that is described inside https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/configure-always-encrypted-keys-using-powershell?view=sql-server-ver15
However the script uses powershell 5 which isn't available to me on linux agents in our azure-devops environment. Because of this a majority of the azure-sql commands aren't available to us. Is there an alternative to these sqlserver module cmdlets.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended alternative is to use the cloud console, but you may be able to get away with linux powershell like so:

I can't guarantee if this all works, but that specific command only creates a `SqlColumnMasterKeySettings` object that contains information about the location of your column master key. You can probably just create one manually, but you'll need to know the exact values. I would recommend running it from a windows machine first to see what the values should be for your environment.

```
# On Windows [Optional]
$cmkSettings = New-SqlAzureKeyVaultColumnMasterKeySettings -KeyURL $akvKey.Key.Kid
$cmkSettings | Format-List KeystoreProviderName,KeyPath

KeystoreProviderName : # Take these strings
KeyPath              : # And use them in your script on linux

# Now on Linux, using the values above:
$cmkSettings = [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.AlwaysEncrypted.SqlColumnMasterKeySettings]::new("YourKeystoreProviderName","YourKeyPath")

New-SqlColumnMasterKey -Name 'CMK1' -InputObject $database -ColumnMasterKeySettings $cmkSettings
# Success!
```

The key settings properties *are* just strings that get saved to your SQL Instance, so this should work fine. The harder part is authenticating to Azure to create keys from your master key, but you can try importing the desktop version of the commands like so:

```
# Start a NEW powershell session without the sqlserver module:
pwsh
# Get the module directory:
$d =  (Get-Item (Get-Module SqlServer).path).DirectoryName

# Import the desktop version of these assemblies:
Import-Module "$d/Microsoft.SqlServer.Diagnostics.Strace.dll"
Import-Module "$d/Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PSSnapins.dll"
Import-Module "$d/Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.AzureAuthenticationManagement.dll"
Import-Module "$d/Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.AlwaysEncrypted.Types.dll"

# Then import the module normally (there will be errors - you can ignore these)
Import-Module SqlServer

# Now you may be able to authenticate to Azure to generate new keys:
# Required to generate new keys
# NOTE: -Interactive fails on linux
Add-SqlAzureAuthenticationContext -ClientID "YourID" -Secret "YourSecret" -Tenant "YourTenant"

# Create a key using your master key:
New-SqlColumnEncryptionKey -Name 'CEK1' -InputObject $database -ColumnMasterKey 'CMK1'
```

This worked on my installation of centos7/pwsh7.1.3 - make sure you have `SqlServer` version `21.1.18245` (only 10 days old at the moment) as many new sql commands got ported to pwsh 7.1.

Comment: Getting a "Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null." on the 2nd line of that script. Maybe I am doing something wrong, but thanks for helping at least.

Comment: @Strike08 In `$d = ...`? Do you have the `SqlServer` module installed? It's just grabbing the module install location and expecting the dll files in there - you can find the paths manually and run `import-module /full/path/to/SqlServer/file.dll`